# Problem in flex project

Tags: apache-flex

I am using **Adobe Flash Builder 4 trial version.**

I created one **abc.mxml** application which is working fine in the IDE. Now, I want to use the generated **abc.swf** in one of my application so I copied

- abc.swf
- abc.html
- and related .js and .css files

to some other location in the file system. After that when I tried to launch the **abc.html** in the browser, nothing was appearing in the browser.

After that I copied the whole **flex project** at some other location and tried to launch the same **abc.html** file. Even that was also not working.

I don't know what's the problem.

**Edited** ============================================================================[image][image]

Comment: Do you have a have a web server that you're trying to access the files from?  Or are you opening the file in your browser using the file path syntax?

Comment: @flextras I am using file path syntax for launching the web page.

Comment: @J_A_X what info you want. I have written everything. Pls tell me if some info is missing which is required for answering the question.

Comment: You've written a description.  You failed to show the code, what you're trying to accomplish, maybe a screenshot of the files, have you tried using Chrome's development tools to see if it's requesting the swf file? the JS file? is it being loaded? Are you using a debug player? Are you seeing a sandbox error? Is this local or through a web server? What do you mean that 'nothing appears'? Just a blank html page or is there a Flash player container there but your swf is missing? etc etc etc

Comment: @J_A_X I have attached two screen_shots. IDE screehshot is showing the project structure on the left side and the internal_browser window on the right side..............Second screenshot is showing the browser_screen when I launched the tpc.html file from my file system...

Comment: Those screenshots doesn't show much either...

Comment: @J_A_X Here is the link to the tpc.html file.... http://www.2shared.com/document/OoMoFrGx/tpc.html

Comment: @J_A_X I don't know how to find whether the swf is being loaded... No I am not using a debug player.. i don't even know what is it as I am totally new to flex... this is local.. no web server is involved. "Nothing is appearing" means that the buttons and text fields that I placed are not visible... only blank screen is there

Comment: download the [flash debug player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) into firefox (don't use Chrome since chrome updates flash automatically and overwrites it).  Check if you're getting an error pop up.  Could you please show some code?  You're probably getting a security sandbox error cause you're trying to get a file locally.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sending my email addy.  I'll get gaggles of newbies emailing Flex questions 24/7 :P  My money is on sandbox security issue.  Either keep the files under bin-debug to prevent it or add your folder *and* flash file to be allowed in the [Flash Security Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Comment: @J_A_X yeah it worked... I added my local folder to the flash security settings... thanks

Answer (score 0):

My money is on sandbox security issue. Either keep the files under bin-debug to prevent it or add your folder and flash file to be allowed in the [Flash Security Settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is cross-site scripting situation, read this: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html.

You launch abc.html (which consist adc.swf) from one domain ("file:///c: ..."), but refers for data from another (is there you red5 installed, probably localhost).

Create cossdomain.xml in the root directory in ther server (red5).